# Cumulative date less than or equal to a period date - T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, date

I am attempting to select the balance of general ledger account from the beginning of the database up through September of this year. I am having difficulty with the WHERE clause. I need to capture all twelve months of data for the previous years but only up through September in 2015. There is no posted date attribute in the database. How my query is written now, it only returns the first 9 months of each year.

```
SELECT
t_leac AS LedgerAccount,
SUM(t_amnt) AS Debit,
t_dbcr AS debit_credit
FROM    
ttfgld106100
WHERE 
t_fyer <= 2015 and t_fprd IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') 
GROUP BY
t_leac,
t_dbcr
ORDER BY
t_leac;
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

I ran the following query and retrieved the minimum value for the t_fyer (numeric) column as 1999 and the minimum value of the t_fprd (numeric) column as 1. Here is what the results looked like:

```
t_fyer    t_fprd
1999        1
1999        2
1999        3
....      ....
1999       13
2000       1
....       ....


SELECT DISTINCT
t_fyer,
t_fprd
FROM
ttfgld106100
ORDER BY
t_fyer, t_fprd
```

Comment: We simply would have no idea as we do not know what the data is. What is the min date? Have you checked? what is the type of t_fyer column?

Comment: `t_fprd`, is that a numeric or text field?

Comment: Both columns are numeric. The min date is t_fyer: 1999 and t_fprd: 1. I am trying to get the summation of the t_amnt up to t_fyer: 2015 and t_fprd: 9. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question by adding a sub query within the select statement. I joined the table to itself by adding the cumulative total up to and including 2014 to the added the 2015 amounts up through September. For reference, here is my code:

```
SELECT
a.t_leac AS LedgerAccount,
(SUM(a.t_amnt) + (SELECT SUM(b.t_amnt) FROM ttfgld106100 b WHERE b.t_fyer <=2014 and a.t_leac = b.t_leac)) AS Amount,
a.t_dbcr AS debit_credit
FROM
ttfgld106100 a
WHERE 
a.t_fyer = 2015 and a.t_fprd IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
GROUP BY
a.t_leac,
a.t_dbcr
ORDER BY
a.t_leac;
```